# How to know TCP connection is closed in net package?

Tags: tcp, go

I'm implementing a small TCP server. How do I know if one of my clients closed? Should I just try to read or write and check if `err` is nil?

Comment: Have you look near [error](http://golang.org/pkg/net/#Error) ?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

That thread "[Best way to reliably detect that a TCP connection is closed](https://web.archive.org/web/20140801101158/http://osdir.com/ml/go-language-discuss/2012-08/msg01586.html)", using `net.Conn` for '`c`' (also seen in [`utils/ping.go`](https://github.com/languid/svnmanager/blob/dcb51fce449565045e0818c320bca2876fe3dd0d/utils/ping.go) or [`locale-backend/server.go`](https://github.com/stevenschmatz/locale-backend/blob/083197fdffb8610f8eccf45bd17f1d98b3e3154e/server.go#L65-L76) or [many other instances](https://github.com/search?q=SetReadDeadline%20%22read%28one%29%22&ref=searchresults&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93)):

```
one := make([]byte, 1)
c.SetReadDeadline(time.Now())
if _, err := c.Read(one); err == io.EOF {
  l.Printf(logger.LevelDebug, "%s detected closed LAN connection", id)
  c.Close()
  c = nil
} else {
  var zero time.Time
  c.SetReadDeadline(time.Now().Add(10 * time.Millisecond))
}
```

For detecting a timeout, it suggests:

```
if neterr, ok := err.(net.Error); ok && neterr.Timeout() {
  ...
```

---

Update 2019: [tuxedo25](https://stackoverflow.com/users/704660/tuxedo25) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12741386/how-to-know-tcp-connection-is-closed-in-golang-net-package/12741495#comment97132452_12741495):

> In go 1.7+, zero byte reads return immediately and will never return an error.
>   You must read at least one byte.

See [commit 5bcdd63](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/5bcdd639331cd7f8d844fd38a674c4751423f938) and [go issue 15735](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/15735)

> ### `net`: don't return `io.EOF` from zero byte reads

Comment: What is the variable `one`? A slice of size zero would make sense.

Comment: @ReyCharles an slice of byte `b []byte` (probably to read at least one byte, hence then name)

Comment: What about using a slice of size zero? Then nothing would be read and we will only check for timeout. `zero := make([]byte,0); ... c.Read(zero); ...`

Comment: @ReyCharles I agree, that makes more sense in this case, but I need to test it first. Maybe it *needs* to read one byte, in order to trigger the EOF.

Comment: Ah, that could happen. It's unfortunate the documentation doesn't say.

Comment: @VonC I have a question: `c.SetReadDeadline(time.Now())` does it mean the timeout will be immediately triggered? And how about `c.SetReadDeadline(time.Time{})`? Is that mean the timeout will never be triggered?

Comment: From http://golang.org/pkg/net/, only `SetReadDeadline(0)` means it never times out. Not sure about the `time.Now()` though.

Comment: In this method, if the byte which read, I require it put back. It seems not possible.

Comment: I don't think this actually works.  I've tried every possible combination that this answer has proposed, and it never detects a closed connection.  I know this, b/c I have this segment of code, and then the program later goes on to do a Write() to the connection and subsequent Read(), which fails with an ErrUnexpectedEOF error due to the fact that the connection has been closed.

Comment: @JayD3e ok, did you try it with the latest go 1.3, just in case something was fixed in a more recent golang release?

Comment: @JayD3e ok. I had it working on Windows back in 2012, but hadn't had the occasion to test it on Windows or other OS with more recent golang releases. On which OS are you trying that code?

Comment: Same here, can't get this code to work on EL6 go 1.4.1. But changed to `c.SetReadDeadline(time.Now())` to `c.SetReadDeadline(time.Now().Add(10 * time.Millisecond))`, it works.

Comment: The url  "Best way to reliably detect that a TCP connection is closed" is broken

Comment: For anyone finding this answer now: In go 1.7+, zero byte reads return immediately and will never return an error. You *must* read at least one byte. [5bcdd63](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/5bcdd639331cd7f8d844fd38a674c4751423f938)

Answer (score 18):

Just try to read from it, and it will throw an error if it's closed. Handle gracefully if you wish!

For risk of giving away too much:

```
func Read(c *net.Conn, buffer []byte) bool {
    bytesRead, err := c.Read(buffer)
    if err != nil {
        c.Close()
        log.Println(err)
        return false
    }
    log.Println("Read ", bytesRead, " bytes")
    return true
}
```

Here is a nice introduction to using the net package to make a small TCP "chat server":

"[Golang Away: TCP Chat Server](https://web.archive.org/web/20160119084158/ttp://www.badgerr.co.uk/2011/06/20/golang-away-tcp-chat-server/)"

Comment: There are lots of possible errors. Only one of them means the connection was closed by the peer.

Answer (score 7):

After struggling for a while on this, here is a POSIX solution that uses `MSG_PEEK` to prevent draining the buffer and causing race conditions. This lets you check the whether the READ half of a TCP socket is still open from another goroutine:

```
func connCheck(conn net.Conn) error {
    var sysErr error
    rawConn, err := conn.(syscall.Conn).SyscallConn()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    err = rc.Read(func(fd uintptr) bool {
        buf := make([]byte, 1)
        n, _, err := syscall.Recvfrom(int(fd), buf, syscall.MSG_PEEK | syscall.MSG_DONTWAIT)
        switch {
        case n == 0 && err == nil:
            sysErr = io.EOF
        case err == syscall.EAGAIN || err == syscall.EWOULDBLOCK:
            // no-op
        default:
            sysErr = err
        }
        return true
    })
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return sysErr
}
```

This is based on the above [mysql#connCheck](https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql/blob/v1.7.1/conncheck.go), but that one does a 1-byte read syscall, which can potentially conflict with other goroutines attempting to read a stream.

Comment: Note that if another goroutine is not actively read()'ing the stream, this will not return EOF until the stream is read and its buffer drained.

Comment: I used with other goroutines and start giving a lot of errors, I find the cause 1 week later, didn't read complete your comment

Answer (score 2):

April 2019 status:

Reading the threads and posts on https://github.com/golang/go/issues/15735

There is a general lack of official support to detect whether a server closed a TCP connection if the server does not write on the connection (reading will fail, but writing won't).

There is a solution provided by https://github.com/methane that works only on Linux and is expensive as it does some allocations -

This is available here: https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql/blob/master/conncheck.go

I found this to be working but not being cross platform is blocking me from adopting it -

Answer (score 0):

I tried the answer above that calls low level socket `Readfrom`, and after good testing I found it will cause problems. While trying to figure out what's wrong I simplified the solution:

```golang
func isConnected(conn net.Conn) bool {
    f, err := conn.(*net.TCPConn).File()
    if err != nil {
        return false
    }

    b := []byte{0}
    _, _, err = syscall.Recvfrom(int(f.Fd()), b, syscall.MSG_PEEK|syscall.MSG_DONTWAIT)
    return err != nil
}
```

And then I discovered this causes deadlines to malfunction, and I filed a [bug](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/65143).

As long as you are not using `conn.SetDeadline` or its read/write variants, the solution works.

Answer (score -3):

My five cents, I figured it is better to write to the connection and get an error, thanks for the answers above, here is my working solution

```
func isTCPWorking(c net.Conn) bool {
   _, err := c.Write([]byte("OK"))
   if err != nil {
      c.Close() // close if problem
      return false
   }
   return true
}
```

Answer (score -4):

```
        _, err := conn.Read(make([]byte, 0))
        if err!=io.EOF{
            // this connection is invalid
            logger.W("conn closed....",err)

        }else{
            byt, _:= ioutil.ReadAll(conn);
        }
```