# How to test TCP disconnection in GO

Tags: go, tcp

I do have a process receiving data from second local process. I need to test if connection errors are handled well AND if it automatically reconnects and keep receiving data after a disconnection.

To do so I am trying to make it disconnect abruptly or put the TCP connection in an error state from a unit test.
As seen in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12741386/how-to-know-tcp-connection-is-closed-in-golang-net-package) to check if a connection is closed I am checking for data to come and test if it returns an error.
I am not sure how to:

- close the connection ungracefully
- make it be in an error state

This is the essence of my data receiver:

```
    import (
        "bufio"
        "encoding/json"
        "fmt"
        "io"
        "net"
    )

    type Message struct {
        ID string `json:"id"`
    }

    func ReceiveData(listener Listener) {
        var tcpConn net.Conn
        var addr string = "127.0.0.1:9999"
        tcpConn, err := net.Dial("tcp", addr)
        socketReader := bufio.NewReader(tcpConn)
        decoder := json.NewDecoder(socketReader)

        for {
            var msg Message
            if err := decoder.Decode(&msg); err == io.EOF {
                listener.ProcessUpdate(Message{}, fmt.Errorf("Received EOF"), nil)
                tcpConn = nil
                return
            } else if err != nil {
                listener.ProcessUpdate(Message{}, nil, fmt.Errorf("Error decoding message: %s", err.Error()))
                tcpConn = nil
                return
        }

        // process message
        _ = msg

        // Test disconnection
        // This does not disconnect:
        // tcpConn = nil
        // This does but gracefully:
        // tcpConn.Close()
    }
```

I am not mocking the TCP connection as I'd like to try with the real data producer. If is needed I'll look at it.

Comment: Exactly what do you mean by closing the connection "ungracefully"?

Comment: Accidental disconnection, people unplugging the cable, powerloss on the other side, malformed tcp messages. I suspect most of these will generate timeouts, I am not aware of all the errors that `tcpConn.Read()` may generate.

Comment: If you want the remote side to simulate a disconnect, like pulling the cable or losing power, make sure keepalive is disabled and just stop responding. If you want to break the connection in various other ways, you need to do that at a lower level on the network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution is to set a [deadline](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#TCPConn.SetDeadline) to the TCP connection itself:

```
tcpConn.SetDeadline(time.Now())
```

Later this will trigger a timeout error which can be caught with:

```
err := decoder.Decode(&msg);
if err != nil {
    if neterr, ok := err.(net.Error); ok && neterr.Timeout() {
        fmt.Errorf("TCP timeout : %s", err.Error())
    } else {
        fmt.Errorf("Received error decoding message: %s", err.Error())
    }
}
```