# Is there a function to detect server disconnection on the client side when a TCP connection is made in golang?

Tags: java, sockets, go

Is there a function to detect server disconnection on the client side when a TCP connection is made in golang?

The server is made in Java, and the client is made in go language.

### in java

```
public class Server {

    public final static int PORT = 8000;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(PORT)) {
            while (true) {
                System.out.println("wait for client's request.");

                try (Socket client = server.accept()) {
                    System.out.println("Connected client information : " + "[" + client.getInetAddress().getHostName() + "]");

                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
                    while (true) {
                        String msg = br.readLine();
                        System.out.println("Client > Server : " + msg);
                    } // end of while(in)
                }catch(IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("Connection with the client has been lost.");
                }
            } // end of while(out)
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("There was a problem establishing the connection.");
        }
    }
}
```

### in GoLang

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net"
    "os"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    log.SetFlags(0)
    for {
        conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", ":8000")
        if nil != err {
            fmt.Println("Connecting to server...")
            time.Sleep(time.Duration(5) * time.Second)
            continue
        }
        for {
            fmt.Println("-to Server")
            fmt.Print("-> ")
            in := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
            s, err := in.ReadString('\n')
            if err != nil {
                log.Println(err)
            }
            str := []byte(s)
            // If there is no input value, it is not passed to the server.
            if len(str) > 2 {
                conn.Write(str)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

or is there a function like JAVA's isConnected in go language?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12741386/how-to-know-tcp-connection-is-closed-in-net-package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```golang
    // Write writes data to the connection.
    // Write can be made to time out and return an error after a fixed
    // time limit; see SetDeadline and SetWriteDeadline.
    Write(b []byte) (n int, err error)
```

When looking onto source code you can clearly see that you are ignoring error when writing to connection. If error happens the connection is most likely no longer valid. You can of course make a function to verify whether connection is valid like this:

```
// note that I assume connection will not ignore nil slice. 
// this might be untrue and thus simple error handling remains.
func isConnected(conn net.Conn) bool {
    _, err := conn.Write(nil)
    return err != nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For my use case, I do the following:

```
connbuf := bufio.NewReader(*r.Conn)
for {
    p := make([]byte, 2048)
    rlen, err := connbuf.Read(p)
    if err != nil {
        if err == io.EOF {
            fmt.Println("EOF")
            r.ConnStatus = false
            return
        } else {
            fmt.Println("Error reading from the TCP Replay Channel", err)
        }
    }
    fmt.Println("Read len :", rlen)
}
```

Basically this will look for io.EOF and if found it will conclude the connection is either lost or closed from the other side.