# How to ensure non-blocking behavior from TCPConn SetDeadline to check from dead peers?

Tags: linux, go, tcp, network-programming

The following question compiles several ways to check for dead peers in TCP connections:
[How to know TCP connection is closed in net package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12741386/how-to-know-tcp-connection-is-closed-in-net-package)

After researching this more, the *typical* situation boils down to:

- The operating system gets a FIN and puts the socket into a CLOSE_WAIT state
- The application needs to issue a socket read in order to detect this state

The main problem is that if you are not monitoring the socket for data at the moment, but still need to detect if it is closed, then you need to poll the status with the read (or read/peek). Given that the default TCPConn Read in go is blocking, the accepted solutions use SetReadDeadline to try to get it to behave in a nonblocking way to make it behave like a poll.

The issue is that SetReadDealine, at least on my go version/architecture, only works when the value given is greater than `Time.Now()`. So the question becomes, **given the following code segment, what is the minimum value for `DeadlineDuration` that will guarantee dead peer detection?**

```golang
one := make([]byte,1)
c.SetReadDeadline(time.Now() + DeadlineDuration)
if _, err := c.Read(one); err == io.EOF {
  c.Close()
}
```

Comment: `SetReadDeadline` does not need to be set in the future, from the docs _`A deadline is an absolute time after which I/O operations fail instead of blocking. The deadline applies to all future and pending I/O, not just the immediately following call to Read or Write.`_. If the read is not returning immediately then it would be classified as a bug. You however are only checking for `io.EOF`, so are ignoring any timeout error. There’s usually no reason to try and poll a socket like this in Go, you can always have a goroutine reading, which will detect immediately when the connection in closed.

Comment: @JimB setting `Time.Now()` or sooner (excluding null time) will immediately emit a wrap of `os.ErrDeadlineExceeded` even if the socket is closed, so the closed socket goes undetected (you don't get the `io.EOF`).

Comment: I see what you're saying now. There is no minimum value which is guaranteed to work. Go is built around blocking method call, so you are usually reading asynchronously to begin with, and will get EOF as soon as the connection closes.

Comment: "if you are not monitoring the socket for data at the moment" I'm having trouble making sense of this.  As JimB says, hand the socket to a goroutine and it can handle the connection, monitoring continuously for data or whatever other state.

Comment: @DanielFarrell assume you have a proxy but the backend session takes a long time to setup. That setup uses a lot of channels to say what resources are ready for the backend. During that time the proxy does not care about the data coming from the frontend, it prefers the OS to just queue it until that backend connection is up. The proxy does care if the frontend conn goes down as it has to start undoing the backend setup tasks.

Comment: The point is that if you are trying to do non-blocking calls you are fighting against the runtime. You can setup direct access to the socket with the proper sycalls and bypass the runtime net poller, but in most cases you should architect the solution to use goroutines for reading and writing the individual connections.